# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, security, tomcat

I'm creating a web application using spring mvc. I have started to incorporate the Spring Security libraries. I'm now getting the following error in the tomcat log when I try to deploy it to tomcat with eclipse.

I'm using the following jar versions in my library

- spring framework version 3.1.1.RELEASE
- spring framework security version 3.1.0.RELEASE

I'm also using STS version of eclipse, maven and  vmware vfabric tc Server (bundled with sts).

Here's the tomcat log

```
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
... 30 more
```

and here's my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<!--
    Display Name is used vides a short name for the application, 
    which will be displayed in the Tomcat Manager application.
    When used in <security-constraint>, this tag provides a name 
    for the security constraint.  
-->
<display-name>ImaginateFramework</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html|*.htm|*.xhtm|*.jsp|*.jsf|*.php|*.pl|*.cf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Security Config -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and here's my spring-servlet.xml file

```xml
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:ldap-server />
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="password"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="bob" password="bob" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.imaginatelabs.imaginate_framework.mvc" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
<mvc:resources location="/scripts/" mapping="/scripts/**" />
<mvc:resources location="/themes/" mapping="/themes/**" />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<!-- Hibernate Components -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Tiles Components -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Language Components -->

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<!-- Theme Components -->
<bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
    <!-- Can I configure this to look in a directory on the server? -->
</bean>

<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>
```

(edit)
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>App</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <org.apache.tiles>3.0.0</org.apache.tiles>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency> 
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You say you're using Maven and you're getting a Class not found error. Can you post your pom?

Comment: Uploaded the pom file hope that helps!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EnvironmentAware is located in the spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, so you are missing that one.

Also recheck your Maven POM file so that you are not missing any other Spring library, like spring-web, spring-webmvc (you may have these since the DispatcherServlet class if found), spring-orm if you use an ORM like Hibernate, spring-jms if you use JMS, etc.

Comment: That was it! I also had to add spring-core to my pom.xml also. I used http://www.jarvana.com/ to figure that out. What were you using?

Comment: I've worked with Spring for so long that I know where is almost anything, but still here are a few tips: 1) If the missing class has a package org.springframework.XXX, then most likely it's in a JAR named spring-XXX-(versionnumber).jar. 2) You can have an empty project that contains all Spring JARs, and then using an IDE like Eclipse you find out where any class is when you open it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the spring-mvc jar on your runtime classpath. Navigate into the exploded war and make sure spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar exists in the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project, and redeploy the project. if it still doesn't work, pls check your spring library carefully if there is any library left.